# My php tables are displaying fine in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-tables

I have tried changing the CSS to make the background black, but this has not worked. I have also searched via google for any solutions to this but have not found any. The web page is displayed against a very dark (almost black) background image and the text and borders for the table are white. They display fine in IE but in Chrome they have a light blue background and the text is almost invisible. Any ideas on how to resolve this would be very gratefully received.

The CSS is:

```
div.vpolls .vpdt {

 margin:.4em 10% .4em .5em;
 background-color: #000000;
 text-align:left;
 font-size:.9em;
 color:#ffffff;
}
```

The url to view the page is http://www.tckennedy.co.uk/government.php
if you view it in IE it looks OK if you view it in chrome it looks awful.

```
<?php

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';

echo '<td width="30"></td>';

echo '<td width="330" valign="top">

<div class="vpolls" id="vp_1">

<div class="vpdt"></div>

<span class="h5">Do you agree with this new system of collecting Council Tax?

</span>

<form action="http://www.tckennedy.co.uk/vpoll/vpoll.php" id="vpf1" method="post"

onsubmit="return votePoll(this);">

<input type="hidden" name="idp" value="1" />

<label for="p1i0"><p>
<input type="radio" name="item" value="Yes" id="p1i0" />Yes</label> 

<label for="p1i1"><input type="radio" name="item" value="No" id="p1i1" />No</label> 

<label for="p1i2"><input type="radio" name="item" value="Undecided" id="p1i2" />

Undecided</label>     

<input type="submit" value="Vote" name="sbm" /> 

<br> <br><span class="p5">
Please note that only one vote per person is permitted       
for each poll</span></p>

</form>

</div></td>';

echo '<td width="10"><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td>';

echo '<td width="330" valign="top">';

include('vpoll/vpoll.php');

echo '<div class="vpolls">'. $obVot->showPoll(1) .'</div>';

echo '</td>';

echo '<td width="290"></td>';

echo '</tr>';

echo '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Since this is a CSS issue, we would need to see that. Not PHP code

Comment: Is it critical that this be asked as a PHP question (and the code displayed in PHP)?  This seems like more of an HTML/CSS question (and if the code was posted that way it would be easier to read).

Comment: Where is the CSS you have tried?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a table for this anyway.

Comment: holy crab!! ie and google chrome has degraded so much, its gives problems with php too!!! that thing must be depriciated or be subject to [cv-pls]

Comment: Please confirm which version(s) of IE you're testing with, and also confirm that IE is rendering the page in standards mode.

Comment: Load the page, view and copy the source HTML, then post in W3 Validator at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input - Your issue is either HTML related or there is a PHP issue in `vpoll/vpoll.php`

Comment: @Spudley if this is the entire code it's working in IE5.5 quirks mode, which I regretfully suspect is true.

Answer (score 0):

style suppose point to `div.vpolls` instead of `div.vpoll .vpdt`

inline css goes like this:

```
<td style="width: 330px; vertical-align: top" ></td>
```

ie accept `<td width="330" valign="top">` because ie6 did but it is not in standard

Comment: Here is the css   div.vpolls .vpdt {
 margin:.4em 10% .4em .5em;
background-color: #000000;
text-align:left;
 font-size:.9em;
 color:#ffffff;
}

Answer (score 0):

where is the css code ?

maybe this can help

```
<style>
body
{
background-color: black;
}
table
{
border-color : white;
}
.p5
{
color: white;
}

</style>
```